# Is there a way to create nested class attributes in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I've been struggling with creating a class for my image processing code in Python.

The code requires a whole bunch of different parameters (set in a params.txt file) which can easily be grouped into different categories. For example, some are paths, some are related to the experimental geometry, some are just switches for turning certain image processing features on/off etc etc.

If my "structure" (not sure how I should create it yet) is created as P, I would like to have something like,

```
P = my_param_object()
P.load_parameters('path/to/params.txt')
```

and then, from the main code, I can access whatever elements I need like so,

```
print(P.paths.basepath())
'/some/path/to/data'

print(P.paths.year())
2019

print(P.filenames.lightfield())
'andor_lightfield.dat'

print(P.geometry.dist_lens_to_sample())
1.5

print(P.settings.subtract_background())
False

print(P.settings.apply_threshold())
True
```

I already tried creating my own class to do this but everything is just in one massive block. I don't know how to create nested parts for the class. So for example, I have a setting and a function called "load_background". This makes sense because the load_background function always loads a specific filename in a specific location but should only do so if the load_background parameter is set to True

From within the class, I tried doing something like

```
self.setting_load_background = False

def method_load_background(self):
    myutils.load_dat(self.background_fname())
```

but that's very ugly. It would be nicer to have,

```
if P.settings.load_background() == True:
    P.load_background()
else:
    P.generate_random_background()
```

Comment: It seems *settings* just have to be an instance of an other class having the method  *load_background*, so there nothing *nested*

Comment: Hi Bruno. Thanks for your reply. I should have been more clear. I was hoping to avoid exactly the solution you proposed. In essence I would like to have all the methods (whether they apply to the file paths, optical geometry etc) available in P.methods and then have all the attributes organised in the sub-groups as described.